# Ember view not working as expected

Tags: ember.js

I came across a weird issue, it might be something easy to fix, or might be missing something, but I can't find what it is. This is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/493/

If you click in the 'Add One' button, you will get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'indeterminate' of undefined
```

that's because of the checkbox, if you remove the checkbox, you will not get anything else. This is only happening when you add the first element to the model. If for instance, you return this in the router:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return [
      {firstName: 'Kris', lastName: 'Selden'},
      {firstName: 'Luke', lastName: 'Melia'},
      {firstName: 'Formerly Alex', lastName: 'Matchneer'}
    ];
  }
});
```

that data will be showed. But the weirdest thing, is that if you replace the whole table in the template, if you replace it for divs, the fiddle will work, what is going on ?. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

Strange!. Another behaviour that I observed is that if the template for `nice` is inlined as below, the checkbox shows up properly. Fiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/495/

On breaking where the exception occurs, the following line shows up.

```
 //Ember.Checkbox :
 didInsertElement: function() {
    this._super();
    this.get('element').indeterminate = !!this.get('indeterminate');
  }
```

So I guess that the parent element is not getting created in this case. But I clueless as to why this is happening.

Comment: yup, I also did the same, and it works that way. The thing is that I can't do that, unfortunately, that view has some logic in it to show a popup on hover, and a few other things. This issue is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Your view creates divs inside of the table element, this causes all sorts of issues inside of most browsers (unless you go html5)

Comment: I am using html5 in my project. I did some tests changing the tagName, in the fiddle, if I add tagName: 'tr', and remove the tr from the template, it works. But unfortunately it doesn't in my project. In my project I'm using ember 1.2. I updated a few weeks ago to that version, it was working before, so, I guess this is an ember issue.